# midl : error MIDL9008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors, idl

I am getting the following error in vs 2008:

> midl : error MIDL9008 : internal compiler problem - See documentation for suggestions on how to find a workaround.
>
> midl: Assertion failed: ( rc < _MAX_DIR ) && ( rc != 0 ), file d:\longhorn\com\rpc\midl\front\filehndl.cxx, line 821

The problem is caused by the following code in the file `%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include\Guiddef.h` on the line I have marked with `<-----`:

```
 #ifndef GUID_DEFINED

 #define GUID_DEFINED

 #if defined(__midl)

typedef struct {

        unsigned long  Data1;
        unsigned short Data2;
        unsigned short Data3;
        byte           Data4[ 8 ];

} GUID;     <------

 #else

 typedef struct _GUID {

        unsigned long  Data1;
        unsigned short Data2;
        unsigned short Data3;
        unsigned char  Data4[ 8 ];

} GUID;

 #endif

 #endif
```

Renaming or deleting "GUID" will solve the internal compiler problem, but of course causes many others. Both the code and the midl.exe executables (from WinSDK v6.0), which are used, are identical to those on an other computer which this error does not happen. Anybody has a better idea than reinstalling Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there was something really badly corrupt. Re-installing Windows and Visual Studio helped though.

Answer (score 1):

My `midl*` files got "corrupted" at some point, either after installing the `Windows 8.1 SDK` with all the sub-components, or when updating Visual Studio 2015 - I guess, as I don't have the exact track of when they might have been overwritten.

Since then, I kept getting `MIDL9008` on compiling a project which was fine before that. `Midlc.exe` was even crashing when attempting to build a certain project.

The solution was to replace the `midl*` files from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86
```

**`(because that's where midlc.exe and midl.exe were starting from, verified by using procmon)`**

with the same files from another machine where the problem was non-existent.

Surprisingly or not, the file sizes for the `midl*` files from the same folders were different, although the reported version numbers were the same! This was a clear indicator that replacing them might fix something.

Copying the files `(midl.exe, midlc.exe, midlrt.exe, midlrtmd.dll)` solved the issue. Very glad I didn't have to reinstall Windows just to fix this annoying and frustrating issue!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If anyone else can confirm this solution works for them, please let me know in the comments and I will mark it as an answer.